# filter out seleteced option from multiple dropdown

Tags: vue.js

I have multiple drop-downs from same api.I would like to filter out the selected code-option from next drop downs.

If i select code1 from first drop down,code1 should not display in 2nd drop down.A computed property for students api will be nice.

```
                    <div>
                      <label class="label">Student1</label>
                    </div>
                    <select class="input"
                      :class="{ 'placeholder':  item1Input === 0 }"
                      v-model="item1Input">
                      <option v-for="(item, index) in students"
                      :key="index"
                      :value="index >
                      {{ item.code}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                      <label class="label">Student2</label>
                    </div>
                    <select class="input"
                      :class="{ 'placeholder':  item2Input === 0 }"
                      v-model="item2nput">
                      <option v-for="(item, index) in students"
                      :key="index"
                      :value="index>
                      {{ item.code}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You can indeed create a computed property with something like `return this.students.filter(st => st !== this.item1Input)`. Are you having trouble with a solution like this ?

Comment: What about there are multiple drop downs. should i write return this.students.filter(st => st !== this.item1Input && == this.item2Input )

Comment: That would be `this.students.filter(st => st !== this.item1Input && sa !== this.item2Input )` but you get the gist of it